# Is this Sentence Correct? "I am accusing him because of the mistake"

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

I was interested in English since when I have started to understand English.

Now when I'm learning "**Prepositions**", I've figured out that:-

i) We have to use **Accuse of** as you can see in this sentence "He is accused of the mistake" 
Another example:- "*I accuse him of his mistake*"

ii) But if I want to use a simple change using **Because of** would it be a mistake? 
iii) Like this sentence:- "*I am accusing him because of his mistake*"

---

Oh! a Simple **FUN FACT** which we can do here with *Voice Change*:-

***Passive Voice:-*** He is accused of the mistake by me.

***Active Voice:-*** I accuse him of the mistake.

Comment: *Accused of the mistake* is an example redundancy! *Accuse* means *that someone has done something morally wrong, illegal, or unkind*. Whereas, you have to specify the charge after *accuse* as *He was accused of robbery*. BTW, What's the fun fact?  Is it you used a passive voice example sentence for Active Voice and an active voice example sentence for Passive Voice?

Comment: You accuse someone **of** an offence. 'Because' is not appropriate in this context, unless you were to say 'I am accusing him because I know she didn't do it' (where they were the only two people present).

Comment: Sorry, For That, I wanted to be sure if I have got "Active" and "Passive" Correct. I have made it exactly the Opposite.       I am changing it!!!